# php variable with javascript echoing

Tags: javascript, php, html

Im working on modifying my page once a user is logged in. (changing the login logo and display welcome username next to it).
so far the img swapworks, but i cannot seem to add $userId into the script to display the sessions username, just the welcome back part works if i remove the $userId. Its weird because when i do this with PHP and HTML it works quite easily.

```
<?php 
if (isset($_SESSION['logged_in'])) { 
    $userId = $_SESSION['username'];

    echo '<script>  
        var img = document.getElementById("imgSwap");
        img.src = "images/lockClosed.png"; 
        </script>';

    echo '<script>
        var userId = '."$userId".';
        var text = document.getElementById("loggedInMsg");
        text.innerHTML = "Welcome Back, + userId"; 
        </script>';        
}
```

Comment: Naming this ID is only going to cause confusion, `$userId = $_SESSION['username'];`  I would just name it what it is `$username = $_SESSION['username'];`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `$userId` is a string, it needs to be quotead in JS.

This should work:

```
<?php 
if (isset($_SESSION['logged_in'])) { 
    $username = $_SESSION['username'];

    // Let's end the PHP block and output our JS
    ?>

    <script>  
        var img = document.getElementById("imgSwap");
        img.src = "images/lockClosed.png"; 

        var username = '<?= $username ?>';
        var text = document.getElementById("loggedInMsg");
        text.innerHTML = "Welcome Back, " + username; 
    </script>;        

    <?php
    // Now when we're done with the JS, open the PHP block again
}
```

In my opinion, it's way easier to end the PHP block instead of echoing HTML and JS using PHP, since you then get some proper syntax highlighting and don't need to care about escaping quotes etc.

(I also changed the variable `$userId` to `$username`, since it's the username we want to output, not the id)

### So, what was the actual issue?

You have a couple of issues:

**First issue**

```
'var userId = '."$userId".';`
```

Since `$userId` here is a string with the username, it wouldn't be quoted and result in: `var userId = foo;` instead of `var userId = 'foo';`.

You need to make quote it like this:

```
'var userId = "' . $userId . '";`
```

As you see, now the `"` is in the JS string instead of around the PHP variable.

**Second issue**

```
`'text.innerHTML = "Welcome Back, + userId";`
```

Here's you're not concatenating the strings, but are literally outputting `"Welcome Back, + userId";`. For the strings to be concatenated, you need to *end* the first string:

```
`'text.innerHTML = "Welcome Back, " + userId;`
```

Comment: this worked. thank you!
im still confused how the other way cannot work though? or can it?

Comment: @crimsonchin - I added an explanation about what the issues with your original code was.

Comment: thanks, everything is clear exept the first issue. Could u post a snippet of how it would look?

Comment: @crimsonchin - Check the updated explanation about what the original issue was and see if it make things clearer.

Comment: Worked like a charm, amazing! ty

Answer (score 0):

It could be the problem of the quotes. you can try include quotes when echo out the value

```
<?php if(isset($_SESSION['logged_in'])){ 
        $userId = $_SESSION['username'];
        echo '<script>  
            var img = document.getElementById("imgSwap");
            img.src = "images/lockClosed.png"; 
            </script>';
        echo '<script>
            var userId = "'.$userId.'";
            var text = document.getElementById("loggedInMsg");
            text.innerHTML = "Welcome Back, + userId"; 
            </script>';        
}
```

Comment: A good answer includes a description about _why_ the OP should try it. What problem does it solve and how?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to concatenate variable to string in javascript  you have to seperate it from string since 
 `+` is just another ASCI character if it is in quotation marks and it does not concatenate : `text.innerHTML = "Welcome Back, + userId";` should be `text.innerHTML = "Welcome Back, "+ userId;`

Comment: true getting confused mixing everything...   tried it but still doesn't work! ;/

Comment: What do you get displayed with `text.innerHTML = "Welcome Back, "+ userId;`?

Comment: nothing at all it outputted the old string from that div